# Getting String equivalent of input in jPasswordField

Tags: java, string, jpasswordfield

I have a code which checks if the user input is ALphanumeric only and checks the strength of the password inputted based on a criteria. A label will appear with a note if:

-Field is **empty**

-**invalid character** is used

and also displays if password is **WEAK, MEDIUM, STRONG,** and **VERY STRONG**

```
this.AlphaNumericOnly(this.jTextField1.getText(),this.warningLbl3);
this.passwordStrength(this.jTextField1.getText(),this.warningLbl4);
```

This method works fine if used in a jtextfield. However I want to use a jpasswordfield to hide user input.

I've already tried:

```
.toString();

String.valueOf();
```

and this loop:

```
char[] input=(this.jPasswordField1.getPassword());
 final_pass = "";
    for(char x : input) {
     final_pass += x;
    }
```

But the method cannot "check" the string I converted.

Here are my methods..

```
public void AlphaNumericOnly(String input,JLabel obj){
if(!"".equals(input)){
    obj.setText(" ");
    warning=false;

    char c[] = input.toCharArray();

    int count = 0;
    for(int x=0; x<c.length; x++){
        if((!Character.isAlphabetic(c[x]))&&(!Character.isDigit(c[x]))){// && c[x]!='-' && c[x]!='(' && c[x]!=')' && c[x]!='+'&& c[x]!='/'&& c[x]!='\\'){
            count=+1;        
        }
    }
    if(count>0){
        obj.setText("*Please use valid characters.");
        warning=true;
    }else{
        obj.setText(" ");
        warning=false;
    }
}else{
    obj.setText("*This Field cannot be left Empty.");
    warning=true;
}   
}
private void passwordStrength(String input,JLabel obj){
   char c[] = input.toCharArray();
   int count=0;
   int notAlphaNumericCount=0;
   for(int j=0;j<c.length;j++){
       if(Character.isAlphabetic(c[j])){
            if(Character.isUpperCase(c[j])){
                count++;
            }
       }else if(Character.isDigit(c[j])){

       }else{
         obj.setText(" ");
         warning=false;
         notAlphaNumericCount++;
       }
   }
if(notAlphaNumericCount==0){   
    if(input.length()<1){
        obj.setText(" ");
        warning=false;
    }else if(input.length()<4){
        obj.setText("Password Strength: WEAK");
        obj.setForeground(Color.red);
    }else if(input.length()<8){
        obj.setText("Password Strength: MEDIUM");
        obj.setForeground(Color.blue);
    }else if(input.length()<10){
        obj.setText("Password Strength: STRONG");
        obj.setForeground(Color.green);
    }else if(count!=0){    
        obj.setText("Password Strength: VERY STRONG");
        obj.setForeground(Color.orange);
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT:**
for a more visual understanding
here is how I use this method:

```
username [Textfield input]- [obj label warning]
password [Textfield input]- [obj label warning]

          [obj label which displays password strength]
```

Comment: Just check the contents of the char array return by the getPassword() method.

Comment: @Sumit Trehan I'm not that good at conversion, could you give me an example please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, as the returning value of `getPassword()` function is char array. you could easily convert it into a string via its constructor.

```
new String(this.jPasswordField1.getPassword());
```

though, personally, I think it would be better to change the `passwordStrength` method's arguments to take a char array instead of String. because you only use the argument `input` to convert it into a char array and to get its length.
And also, you will create a new String object every time you construct a String via this way.

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to add that line of code, I have already tried that and It also didn't work

Comment: hmm, can you please explain to me what didn't work? is there any error message? and the method you're referring to is `AlphaNumericOnly` or `passwordStrength`?